# ¿Como desarrollar una aplicación de bloqueo de pantalla en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen día.
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de cyber en **C# (Windows Forms)** y tengo problemas para bloquear todo; es decir, la aplicación inicia y debe bloquear la pantalla total, las teclas de: `Windows, tab, Windows+Tab, Alt+Tab y otros deben desactivarse`. No permita realizar ninguna operación.

Un ejemplo claro es este programa `Ukey` (http://ldc.mx/ukey.php), aplicación que bloquea la *PC* impidiendo el uso de esta si no se ingresa la contraseña, bloquea todas las teclas especiales, excepto las letras y/o numero para ingresar password.

Mi aplicación bloquea la pantalla pero al hacer *Windows+D* se minimiza y se tiene acceso.

La aplicación está desarrollada en **C# para Windows Form (.Net)** en *Visual Studio*.

Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: pero porque no controlas esto mediante el login de windows? cuando quieres bloquear desde la aplicacion lanzas un logoff para que windows pida nuevamente las credenciales de autenticacion en la pc

Comment: Explico nuevamente: La aplicación tiene un contador de tiempo, si el usuario de sesión windows no usa la pc el tiempo de corte se activa y luego bloquea la pantalla. Si quiere trabajar ingresa el password y nuevamente se inicia el tiempo de conteo. Si lanzo un "logoff" la aplicación no iniciaría con el mismo usuario cuando se inició, ya solo pide password y no nombre de usuario cuando retoma la sesión y no es nueva.

Answer (score 1):

**Método 1:**
Incluye la librería:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Desde el código llama a:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe", "user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
```

**Método 2**
Incluye la librería siguiente:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Y haz referencia al método siguiente en una de tus clases:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
```

Para mandarlo llamar usa la función LockWorkstation, por ejemplo en un programa de consola:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LockWorkStation();
    }
```

Fuente: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745788/how-do-i-lock-a-windows-workstation-programmatically